# Sending POST request to another application running on the same server but on a different port

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have two expressJS web applications that run on two different ports (88 & 8443). One application needs to send a POST request to the other. I am using axios ( have also tried requestjs) but I'm not getting any response from the other server.

I'm not sure if the server is sending any request at all since after few minutes it gets the **"connect ETIMEDOUT"** error.

Is there any better way to communicate to another application on a different port ?

**CODE**

```
// Posting Server
data = JSON.stringify({key: 'pair'});
axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }})
    .then((resp) => {
        if (resp.status == 200)
            console.log('Done")
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));


// Receiving Server
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Comment: Can you please update relevant code ?

Comment: your code doesn't show the server initializing logic where we can confirm if the servers are initialized with right ports, and also the url you are passing in the `axios.post` call .